# muti-domain oauth in facebook

Tags: facebook, oauth

I'm using facebook oauth for a cross site login function.
In facebook they require me to config the domain of the app for secure reason,but I have 3 domains which will apply the program,while in facebook,I can only add one domain.

If the domain is not add in facebook,it will show an error says the redirect_uri is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the redirect URL does have to match the setting you've entered into facebook.  I can think of two options.

- Register 3 different apps with facebook?  Now your 3 different domains also have 3 different app ids and app secrets.
- Register 1 app with facebook.  Have the authorize URL point to 1 domain, which is smart enough to redirect the user back to the correct domain.

Comment: thanks.I thought about your solutions,If register 3 different apps,there will cause I have to ideitity user's access_token belongs to which app and make the next api call. If using a single domain to redirect ,it will cause 1 time unecessary redirection.